# How we can run java in Chrome45 onwards

Tags: java, google-chrome, npapi

As we know, Chrome 45 onwards, there is no support for NPAPI. So How we can run webaaplication which are using java or applet with latest version of chrome?

I know the one alternate way that by using the IE tab extension in chrome, but i am searching for another approach.
is/Will oracle provide something for this?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: You're unlikely to to see the return of java applet support in Chrome due to the well publicised security problems. You'll need to stay with the earlier versions if you have an existing web app to support.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid Java applets in your application (or) Convert your applets to HTML, using Ajaxswing kind of software. Oracle didn't provide any alternative.

Ajaxswing ref: http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/